# How to properly re-initialize an array of returned data

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

In my single page Angular app I have a controller, which makes calls to a data service.
In the data service the results are being pushed onto an array named _result.
On any subsequent calls to the data service, the _result array is being appended to, instead of being emptied out first, which results in a duplicate data being passed to the controller and displayed in a view.
I am very new to Javascript, and asking for help to ensure that any additional calls to data service only return unique data.
Here is my controller:

```
angular.module('frontEndApp').controller('ViewExistingRequestsCtrl', ['$scope', 'requestsRepository',
    function ($scope, requestsRepository) {

        $scope.sendrequest = requestsRepository.getServiceRequests();

        $scope.requests = requestsRepository.result;

    }]
);
```

And here is my data service, which has the _result array:

```
frontEndApp.factory('requestsRepository',function ($http) {
    var _result = [];
    var postServiceRequest = function (ServiceRequest) {
        $http(
        {
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/ServiceRequests', method: "POST", data: ServiceRequest,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("postServiceRequest Status: " + status);
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("postServiceRequest FAILURE: " + status + "  ServiceRequest:  " + ServiceRequest);
        });
    };
    var getServiceRequests = function () {
        $http({
            method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/ServiceRequests'
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

            for (var key in data) {
                _result.push(data[key]);
            } console.log(_result)
            return _result;
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            return status;
        });
    };
    return {
        postServiceRequest: postServiceRequest, getServiceRequests: getServiceRequests, result: _result
    };
});
```

Comment: `_result = []`, before pushing data onto it, also why are you trying to return stuff in the success/error callbacks they dont return to anything.

Comment: Patrick, you were correct - I was not returning anything in a standard callback pattern, as I should have. I have now refactored the collaboration between the service and the controller, so the controller gets to execute a callback function, defined in the service. That was my main hangup - to really understand the callback nature here. Now this part of my app works as expected, without any need for _result. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Just redefine it as an empty array before populating it:

```
...

$http({
        method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/ServiceRequests'
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        _result = []; // <---- this is the key!
        for (var key in data) {
            _result.push(data[key]);
...
```

Comment: As it was pointed out, I was not returning anything in a standard callback pattern, as I should have. I have now refactored the collaboration between the service and the controller, so the controller gets to execute a callback function, defined in the service. That was my main hangup - to really understand the callback nature here. Now this part of my app works as expected, without any need for _result. Thank you very much!